# how can I redirect example.com to www.example when I use s3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS Cloudfront to distribute my homepage.

http://www.example.com, https://example.com, http://example.com

All three URLs must be redirected to the main url https: // www.example.com.

The problem is that the https://example.com domain failed to redirect.

I created a www.example.com bucket on s3 and distributed it to cloudfront with an SSL certificate (user aws certificate manager). and I connect cloudfront endpoint to www.example.com url used by route53. So the http://www.example.com => https://www.example.com redirect is a success.

Then I created an example.com bucket on s3 and move to properties > static website hosting > redirect requests then setting target bucket = www.example.com and protocol = https

The result is that http://example.com succeeds in redirecting to https://www.example.com, but https://example.com to https://www.example.com fails to connect.

Did you solve the same problem?

Thank you.

update my cloudfront settings
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it,

**SSL Certificates:**

```
example.com
*.example.com
```

**CloudFront Distribution 1:**

```
CNAME example.com 
Certificate: example.com
Viewer Protocol Policy -- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
Origin and Behaviour --
   To S3 Bucket to redirect
   Redirect to https://www.example.com
```

**CloudFront Distribution 2:**

```
CNAME www.example.com 
Certificate: www.example.com
Viewer Protocol Policy -- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
```

Also, note *.example.com certificate won't match example.com certificate.

Comment: Although it does not become a forced redirect to www, it can be deployed as a single source. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I bet I can guess what's happening here. On your Origin configuration in CloudFront, you can set the `Origin Protocol Policy` to connect to the origin with `HTTP`, `HTTPS` or `Match Viewer`. If you have it set to `Match Viewer` it will attempt to connect to the S3 Static hosting for your domain via HTTPS, which can be problematic. Instead, set it to `HTTP` and then things will probably work.

Also, you might want to split your `example.com` distribution from your `www.example.com` distribution, as CloudFront differentiates behaviours associated with origins usually based on Path.

Comment: Hello, I do not understand setting it to http. Is it a cloudfront setting issue? I added a cloudfront setting picture to my question. Is it a problem I set http redirect to https?

Comment: If you look under the origins tab, and select the origin you have associated with `example.com`, look at the `Origin Protocol Policy`. S3 Static Hosting only supports `HTTP` connections, so if this is set to `HTTPS` or `Match Viewer` that would cause a problem.

Comment: Also for the Redirecting origin, be sure to use the S3 Static Website Hosting domain, it will look something like `example.com.s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com` as otherwise, you bypass the redirection rules.

Comment: I update second image in question 
I added example.com in cloudfront origins tab and example.com route53 value change to www.example.com cloudfront endpoint but...
when I access `http://example.com` cloudfront return error bad request

Comment: And I changed ssl cretificate to `*.dgdr.co.kr`

Comment: OK, so in the last edit, you removed your behaviours tab image, but in that image, it appears that all traffic was directed to the www.dgdr.co.kr bucket, through an S3 origin. I haven't had much luck with these myself, and usually end up using a Custom origin to the s3 static website domain, as mentioned in my previous comment. Also, You probably want a separate distribution for your dgdr.co.kr domain, as I mentioned in my answer, CloudFront differentiates behaviours only based on Path, not domain.

Comment: Kannaiyan's answer is not perfect for me (because it isn't forced redirect url), but it is resolved that using two cloudfront instance with two s3 buckets of the same code. Thank you very much for your kind answers.

Comment: @byunghyung park: what do you mean by forced redirect? Like any file on example.com should send you to the base of www. Example. Com